# Losing monitor input - PSU or GPU suspect

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I randomly lose video after playing games once in a while (mainly guildwars 2) regardless of graphics quality.

Computer still produces sounds and appears working, but monitor reports no input.

I have monitored temperatures and they seem okay across the board.

Auto configuration by bios of both voltages and other similar options such as cool and quiet seem to make no difference as far as the problem happening.

Processor being overclocked and fiddling with voltages (within reasonable ranges) of VCORE and FSB has done nothing.

At this point I'm unsure if it's a video card or PSU issue - but since there's no forum for both at once, I figured I'd post here.

Specs:

```
Gigabyte 970A-UD3 V1.1
AMD FX 4170 @ Stock (made no difference when 4.7 Ghz @ 1.45v VCORE)
Corsair H50 CPU Cooler
Kingston KHX1600C9D3k2 2*4 GB (PC3 12800 at 1.65v - also used it at 1333 mhz at 1.5v)
XFX R7770 Core Edition
4 80mm Case fans
WD Caviar Blue 500gb HDD
Rosewill 630w (R630-S12) single rail PSU with 50A +12V rail
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm quite confident it's not a PSU issue. Borrow a different monitor, if the problem persists get a new video card.

Answer (score 0):

While playing check if your GPU/PSU isn't overheating. Either the components are burning, or something is automatically turning it off to avoid damage to the board. 80-100 Degrees Centigrade is hot enough for either of the above to happen. If it is, then you might need a  better cooling system.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that it's a PSU issue. Since you have a single rail PSU, it would not stop powering only the graphics card. It could however be an issue with the power being supplied to the card. Check the power cables that lead to the card, use different ones and reseat the card in it's PCI-E slot. Also check the PCI-E bus (overclocking) settings in your BIOS, make sure they are stock. If this doesn't help, it's most likely a graphics card issue, test with a different card, different output on the card, different cable or monitor.